# Would Levite girls be able to sing in the temple?

Tags: women, beis-hamikdash, song-poetry

I assume the halacha that [the voice of a woman is like nakedness](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.24a.17?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) only applies to girls over the age of bat mitzva, if so would Levite girls younger than that age have been able to participate in the singing of the Levi'im in the temple?

Comment: Were women allowed to serve in the Beis HaMikdash?

Comment: Consider registering your account. Also consider sourcing your claims to the best of your ability. For example, how do you know that a voice is like nakedness? (Even clarifying that this is something you have heard from rabbis, friends, or others, for example, strengthens the question). You might also consider clarifying why you think it would only refer to girls from bat mitsvah.

Comment: Note that your title asks whether they would have been able to, (i.e. whether there was any possible problem), then you consider whether or not a given problem would apply. There could have been reasons for them not to do sing in in the Temple beisides for the issue you raise. (Note that the issue is Talmudic; there is no evidencethat at the time of the Temple hearing a woman singing was considered objectionable. Interestingly, it is not at all clear that prohibition is even defined by singing; the Talmud speaks of voices; which voices, and of which women, is subject to interpretation).

Comment: "I assume the halacha that the voice of a woman is like nakedness only applies to girls over the age of bat mitzva" Why in the world would you assume that?

Comment: See Erkhin 11a and 13b, and of course Kiddushin 52b

Comment: Hey, not-allowed, your username looks familiar; is [this other account](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1561/not-allowed-to-change-my-name) also yours? If so, you might not know that you can [ask for them to be merged](/help/merging-accounts). That way, you can keep track of all of your activity here in one place. (If it is you, welcome back! `:-)`)

Comment: @Ezra Nomen est omen? https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a02.htm#65

Comment: @Kazi bácsi That seems like an answer

Comment: Does Ovarian Yosef rule that women singing psalms and holy texts aren't considered nakedness at all?

Answer (score 1):

Only male Levites from the age of thirty and up were allowed to serve in the Temple. This includes singing ([Rashi to Numbers 8:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.8?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.8.25.1&lang2=bi)), which is an integral part of the Temple service, and not just aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: -1 this is simply false. Aside from the partial source and even more questionable citation, this doesn't address who else is allowed to sing with the formal base set of 12 leviim.

Comment: @DoubleAA This is sourced directly from the Rashi's to the Chumash there. Rashi is based on the Sifri and Gemara in Chullin, which you can find by using the links in Sefaria.

Comment: Well, a small part of it is sourced to there. Parts of it are straight inaccurate and parts needed to fully answer the question are simply missing. Not great.

Comment: @DoubleAA This unfortunately isn't the first time you've missed the point. The question was can girls sing in the Temple. The answer is clearly no, as there are requirements to be able to sing there, as stated in the Rashi, and earlier in the Gemara. Nothing in my answer is inaccurate, and you have yet to point to anything that you think is.

Comment: I'm not missing the point. You are. There's a reason halachic questions aren't usually answered in responsa by citing rashi on chumash. You don't get the whole picture or know what applies lehalacha and what doesn't. The gemara in multiple places clearly indicates opinions that people other than 30 year old male levites sang in the Temple.